# Ajax checkbox selection (older code, worked with jQ v1.3)

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code works on one of my dev boxes (using JQ v1.3.2.)  I just updated to the latest JQ version and it no longer works.  I notice when looking at the form data being submitted by Chrome, I'm passing "MessageID[]" which explains why my function is complaining about missing messageIDs.  Can someone put me out of my misery and tell me how I can fix?  (urg, sorry... i know this is something is should know.)

Thx as always.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="message"  value="#messageID#" />


$('.move').click(function(e){                         
var folderID = $(this).attr('data-id');                                
var selected = new Array();
$("input:checkbox[name=message]:checked").each(function() {
 selected.push($(this).val());
});
$.post(
<cfoutput>"My.cfc?method=moveMessage&ID=123&time=#now()#", </cfoutput>
{folderID: folderID, messageID: selected },
function() {
loadMessages();
});  
  return false; 
  alert('Please select at least one message.')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want the "traditional" form of parameter serialization (which won't include the `[]`). To get this option, you're going to have to convert your `$.post` into a `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { folderID: folderID, messageID: selected },
    url: <cfoutput>"My.cfc?method=moveMessage&ID=123&time=#now()#", </cfoutput>
    success: function () {
        loadMessages();
    },
    traditional: true // <-- use "traditional" param serialization
});
```

You can also set this property globally as specified in the documentation for `serialize`:

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects
>   recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks
>   such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality
>   globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Comment: @Kerrie: No problem, that one has bitten me before too :)